# First Transition not working because initial height is not set

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am working with a `<div>`in a Webapp which is minimizable via a toggle button. Pressing the button changes the height of the `<div>` which works fine and uses `transition: .4s;`.

The Problem is: The First time the button is pressed, the height changes sudden and without any transition. The other pressed work just fine. This is because the height of the `<div>` is not initially set, but `min-height, max-height` are. So I've tried, when the button gets pressed the first time, to get the height of the div via javaScript and then just set the height to this. Sadly, the transition still doesn't work the first time.

I'm using Polymer btw.

I hope you got some tips, thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css

Comment: Can you show the HTML, CSS & JS please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to animate `max-height` and not `height`.

So you dont have to get the initial height via JS.